# Best way to programmatically pick initial view controller OS X Cocoa

Tags: xcode, swift, segue, viewcontroller, nsview

I am trying to programmatically select an initial view controller for my Swift Cocoa application in Xcode. I am grabbing information from the terminal, and based on that information, I want to have the application choose between two different view controllers. Basically an if/else statement after I figure out how to be able to choose. Does anyone know how to programmatically pick the initial view controller (so I can have it choose between 2), instead of simply use the segue to pick one controller all the time? I can't seem to find much information about it, and the iOS post about it haven't been very useful in this situation.